# Using dynamic objects across assemblies

Tags: c#, dynamic

I can't get dynamic objects to work in types in other assemblies. To replicate this, create a new solution, add a class library, add a console application, add a reference to the class library to the console application, create this class in the class library:

```
public class DynamicTest
{
    public dynamic People { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var person in People)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(person.Name);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

And insert this into the console application's `Program.Main()`:

```
var test = new DynamicTest
{
    People = new[] { 
        new { Name = "John" },
        new { Name = "Jane" }
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Run the console application. On the `sb.AppendLine` line in the `DynamicTest` class, a `RuntimeBinderException` is thrown with the message `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'`.

If I move the `DynamicTest` class into the console application assembly it works as expected. Is there a limitation with using dynamic across assemblies? This seems to be a pretty reasonable use case for dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general consensus for this is to use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) - which is the equivalent that can cross app boundaries.

EDIT: Man, I forgot how the compiler treated `dynamic` until now.. it's fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Simon Whitehead's answer, `ExpandoObject` needs to be used on the consuming side, i.e. in `Program.Main()`:

```
dynamic john = new ExpandoObject();
john.Name = "John";

dynamic jane = new ExpandoObject();
jane.Name = "Jane";

var test = new DynamicTest
{
    People = new ExpandoObject[] {
        john,
        jane
    }
};
```

Comment: If there's a neater way to implement this I would love to know. Probably F#. Or Ruby.

Comment: Maybe instead of duck typing it should be called */ducks* typing